# Updating a rectangle list

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing, drawrectangle

Am drawing multiple rectangles in a windows form using graphics.DrawRectangle and is adding every rectangle to a rectangle list.later am editing the location a nd size of these rectangles.my doubt is whether i can edit the values of a rectangle in a rectangle list?

Comment: Short answer is "yes".

Comment: You can not use `list[0].X = 100;` because `Rectangle` is structure and is value type. You need to assign a new `Rectangle` with new location and size to the same index. When you write `list[0].X=100;`, it's like `var r = list[0]; r.X=100;`. Since rectangle is value type, after `var r = list[0];`, `r` is a new instance which is a copy of `list[0]` so changing `r.X` doesn't change `list[0].X`. Compiler detects the mistake and generates this error: *Cannot modify the return value of 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Drawing.Rectangle>.this[int]' because it is not a variable*.

Comment: @Reza Aghaei thanks for that suggestion.that helped me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
Rectangle temp = RectList[0];
temp.Width = 100;
temp.Height = 100;
temp.X = 0;
temp.Y=0;
RectList[0] = temp;
```